# JavaScript - why the push is not working and throwing exceptions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can i have pc.id and pc.quantity by keeping the existing pc as it is? doing following is not working getting exception

```
//Example Python pc_config is assigned to pc : var pc = {{ pc_config | safe }};
function createPeerConnection() {
  try {
    var element = {};
    element.id = 'test001';
    element.quantity = '30';


    pc.push(element);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(pc));

    // i want to have : pc.id  or pc.quantity without losing the default values already 
    // pc was assigned by Python

  } catch (e) {
    console.log("FAIL");
    return;
  }

}
```

Comment: did u declare array pc=[]

Comment: pc is array or object?

Comment: As alluded above .push is an array method. If pc is not an array you can push all you want but it won't yield.

Comment: pc is assigned like this in Javascript: `var pc = {{ pc_config | safe }};` using Google App Engine , python is assigning the pc_config as ` 'pc_config': json.dumps(pc_config)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

push only exists on array

you could simply add the element directly in case you want pc.id & pc.quantity

```
pc.id = element.id;
pc.quantity = element.quantity;
```

or in case you want to use it as an array, check jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fe9Z3/

In this case, i define a push function to pc, which checks what was your latest indexer, and add a new element. You should only add the push to pc once, after you initialize its value though.

```
function jsonNormal() {
    var el = document.getElementById('json_normal');
    var pc = {};

    pc.push = function(val) {
        var i = 0;
        while (typeof pc[i] !== 'undefined') {
            i++;
        }
        pc[i] = val;
    };

    var element = { id: 'test', quantity: 30 };
    var element2 = { id: 'test2', quantity: 40 };

    pc.push(element);
    pc.push(element2);

    el.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(pc);
}
```

This example uses the prototype function of an array, which requires an attribute length inside your pc element, the push function is then added to your object (again, only add it once :))

```
function jsonArray() {
    var el = document.getElementById('json_push_array');
    var pc = {length:0};
    pc.push = Array.prototype.push.bind(pc);

    var element = { id: 'test', quantity: 30 };
    var element2 = { id: 'test2', quantity: 40 };

    pc.push(element);
    pc.push(element2);

    el.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(pc);
}
```

### update based on comments

This does however leave only the latest push, it is possible that when no id was defined on the second add, the first id is still remaining (you could however make sure that id is at least defined as null on your element)

Jsfiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/3ULy8/

```
    pc.push = function(val) {
        if (typeof val === 'undefined' || !val) {
            return;
        }
        for (var i in val) {
            if (!val.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                continue;
            }
            pc[i] = val[i];
        }
    };
```

Comment: +1 - this solved the problem: `pc.push = Array.prototype.push.bind(pc);`

Comment: Why i get undefined ? when i try: `pcConfig.push = Array.prototype.push.bind(pcConfig);
    var element = { id: 'test', quantity: 30 };
    pcConfig.push(element);
    console.log(">>>>>>>>>> " + pcConfig.id);`

Comment: Here i want pcConfig.id to print me 'test' but its saying undefined

Comment: push indexes your values (you are doing it array style, now). Read it as `pcConfig[0].id`, `pcConfig[1].id`, etc ...

Comment: I understand you. but there is one problem, i am working with one large framework which needs `pcConfig.id` not `pcConfig[0].id` if i change like you suggested now, it will conflict with everything. pcConfig.id is optional sometimes its available or not in case its not available i need to add it in that large framework.

Comment: I updated my answer still to your above last comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You can only push to an Array.
Just add this Line before you declare the function.

```
var pc = [];

function createPeerConnection() {
   .....
```